# Deauthorise Apple ID from the Mac App Store

Tags: mac, mac-appstore, xcode, apple-id

I have Xcode installed using an Apple ID that I want it to be detached from. How can I login to the Mac App store using a different Apple ID and then have Xcode reattached to the new account in order to be updated? Not too sure if Mac App store and iTunes are using the same Apple ID.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to delete Xcode, sign out of the Mac App Store, sign in with the new ID and "buy" Xcode again from the Mac App Store.

Comment: Will my current projects get deleted?

Comment: No, but you will no longer be able to update them without signing in to the account they were purchased on.

Comment: Can i just copy those?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Each Apple ID is, in Apple's view, for a different person and is the key to their DRM. You can continue to use the apps, even though you are not signed with the Apple ID that purchased them. If an update comes out for them you will not be able to get the new version without signing in with the purchasing Apple ID. Purchases can not be transferred between accounts, they must be repurchased with the new Apple ID.